# how to parse an enum just based on a string?

Tags: c#

I have an xml file that I store various different enum names, I now need to be able to read that enum name out of the file and convert it to a list of that values just based on the string form of the enum name. is there any way to do this?I dont have the enum type and that is my problem with this.

Comment: You also need to know the enum type. Then you can use [Enum.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Wanted to post this as an answer before this question got closed: If you are using the `XmlSerializer` to read your xml, simply add some [`XmlEnumAttribute`s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlenumattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to your enum members.

Comment: Some tips for your next question: Post the code you are using now, where it goes wrong, what you have tried so far, etc. Recommended reading: [mcve]